# Disable SSL security in akka http client

Tags: scala, ssl, akka-http

I have to make https calls to an api that appears to not have validated SSL certificate. I would still like to make calls to the api using the `Http().singleRequest` method of akka-http.

When I make a call, I however get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

When I make a call with curl, I get

```
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it.
```

The calls with curl however work if I had the flag `--insecure`.

In akka-http, I tried the following:

```
val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(
      s => s.withLoose(
        s.loose
          .withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)
          .withAllowLegacyHelloMessages(Some(true))
          .withAllowUnsafeRenegotiation(Some(true))
          .withAllowWeakCiphers(true)
          .withAllowWeakProtocols(true)
          .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
          .withDisableSNI(true)
      )
    )
    val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)


    Http()
      .singleRequest(
        HttpRequest(
          HttpMethods.POST,
          uri = Uri("https://..."),
          protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`
        ),
        connectionContext = badCtx
      )
```

but I still get the same error.

What should I do to fix the issue?

PS: I understand (given the many warnings in akka-http docs) that it is something that I shouldn't do in production but I'd like this workaround to work for now...

Comment: `withDisableSNI` is not a good idea. This has nothing to do with certificate validation at all but disables sending of the hostname within the TLS handshake. Failing to send the hostname will cause errors with sites which require SNI - which are a lots of sites today (like all sites behind Cloudflare and other CDN).

Comment: Ah right. I thought that disabling more things could not hurt but I understand the concern. I deleted the line but it however keeps the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem some time ago and as far as I remember it had to do with [this issue](https://github.com/lightbend/ssl-config/issues/69). Workaround for that problem is to have own implementation of SSLContext that will accept just anything. Implementation is pretty straightforward and the example can be found in the last comment of of issue linked above.

Comment: Indeed, it works like a charm! Here's the direct link to the snippet for reference: https://gist.github.com/iRevive/4a3c7cb96374da5da80d4538f3da17cb